# Handling SPA url requests

Tags: http-headers

I have a SPA application which should always serve `index.html` from whatever the link assuming the static resource doesn't exist:

```
/
/index.html
/my-fancy-page
/some/really/long/url
```

I have this working fine, however I am trying to minimize the requests made to my server so the page loads as quickly as possible (I've already made other optimizations in this area: vulcanize, gzip, etc...)

If the user makes the following request: `/some/really/long/url`, is there anything I can send down to the browser such that it knows to load `index.html` for this URL without actually forcing a redirect - I want `/some/really/long/url` to show in the url still? (which it may have already cached)

Comment: _"without actually forcing a redirect"_ - yes, by _rewriting_ all URLs to the index.html file?

Comment: That's what I am doing now (I think)...however I have to return `index.html` file contents in the body, which I am trying to avoid given that its already been cached by the browser...

Comment: Using the proper caching headers causing a conditional request that'll work just fine.

Comment: I think that is the crux of my question - what headers do i need? If I visit `/index.html`, then open a new tab and visit `/some/really/long/url`, I expect the browser to load `index.html` from cache. Currently I have to return `index.html` contents for it to work correctly.

Comment: Yeah I wonder if you can let a browser issue a conditional request for a resource it never requested.